# java - How to return random String from an array using methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to make a method that randomly chooses one of the strings in my "carmake" array. I am stuck in my setCarMake method. The same applies for the color of the car(that method will be made after i finish this one). 
Here is my current code.

```
public class Cars {

    public String[] carmake = {"Audi", "BMW" , "Mercedes-Benz", "Lexus", "Volkswagen"};
    public String[] carcolor = {"Black", "Yellow", "Red", "Grey"};
    //
    public int caryear;
    public int speed;

    public void setCarMake(){
        Random rand = new Random(14335);
        carmake.rand.nextInt(carmake.length);
    }

    public int GetYear(){
        int max = 2015;
        int min = 1999;

        Random rand = new Random();
        caryear = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min ;
        return caryear;
    }

    public void execute(){
        System.out.println(caryear + " " + carmake);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: `setCarMake()` does not return a value. You need to set the return type to `String` and add a `return` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
carmake.rand.nextInt(carmake.length);
```

Because it means that rand is an method of carmake array?? Doesn't make sense, right? That's what dot `.` operator does. They are used to [access method.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

Try this:

```
int carMakeRandomIndex = new Random().nextInt(carmake.length);
return carmake[carMakeRandomIndex];
```

Also, please follow the naming convention.

Comment: @ChuckBIhekwaba Check [working demo](https://ideone.com/Jmlrta) . Show how you are calling that method

Comment: how do i print the car name as a string? it only returns the index number not the name.

Comment: @ChuckBIhekwaba If you return `carMakeRandomIndex`, it will return index, if you return `carmake[carMakeRandomIndex]`, it will return car name at that index. Show your code if you still have trouble and I will take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to get a random number in the range of the array (0 to carmake.length - 1) and then use that as the array index.

```
rand.nextInt(carmake.length); //This should work
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to obtain a random element from the carmake array:

```
final int randomIndex = rand.nextInt() % rcarmake.length;
return carmake[randomIndex];
```

Comment: the expression `rand.nextInt() % rcarmake.length` may be biased in the sense that not all index values appear with the same probability.

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String;@677327b6 - that is the output for your code. Similar thing happened to me earlier.

Comment: @ChuckBIhekwaba this is not the output of his code snippet. Your trying to print 'carmake', not the returned random String.